# Subtract/add float from/to date - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a float, e.g. 76.8 which I need to add to now(). I tried below but it seems to me that it takes 76, not 76.8 while I need 8 to be also taken into account:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setTime(today.getTime()+76.8);
```

Comment: Numeric timestamp values are always interpreted as integers. They measure the number of milliseconds since an original fixed point in time.

Comment: To confirm what you are saying, there is no way to add/subtract 76.8?

Comment: @EkaterinaPonkratova By adding 76.8 do you want to add 76 minutes and 48 seconds ?

Comment: @EkaterinaPonkratova what do you intend "76.8" to mean? For JavaScript, it means 76 milliseconds. You could round the value up or down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where the float comes from but if that's the requirement, you could do something like this maybe:

```
var floating = 76.8;
// check how many numbers are after the floating point
var n = (n + "").split(".")[1];
var multiplier = 1;
if(n > 0) {
multiplier = Math.pow(10, n);
}

today.setTime((today.getTime() * multiplier + floating * multiplier)/multiplier);
```